# Motivation for taylor series of $\mathrm{e}$

Tags: real-analysis, education

A classical way to introduce "Euler's number" $\mathrm{e}$ is via compound interest which leads to

$$
\mathrm{e} = \lim_{n\to \infty} \left (1 + \frac{1}{n} \right )^n 
$$

Is there a also such a real world motivation for

$$
\mathrm{e} = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!}
$$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)#History

Comment: This might be a tangential comment, but my favorite way to discover $e$ is to compute the derivative of $b^x$ where $b>0$. We find the derivative is a scalar times $b^x$. Then we ask, for which value of $b$ would that scalar equal $1$. This yields an expression for $e$ similar to the first expression you mentioned.

Comment: littleO: This is how I did in my  calc 1 class. I introduced it as something that we cannot avoid if we are to derive power functions. It is so natural this way, I think.

Comment: Yet another nice intro is this. $\frac{1}{t}$ is a continuous function, so $$\int _0 ^ x t^{-1}dt$$ exists and its derivative is $x^{-1}$. Since harmonic series diverges so does our function. Thus its range covers $0$ to infinity. Now $e$ is the unique solution to $$ \int _0 ^ x t^{-1}dt = 1.$$ This way one can introduce $e^x$ as inverse function to $\ln x$ and express any other power in terms of this one. Most properties of $e^x$ can be derived solely by change of variables in the integral.

Comment: @Behnam nitpick: your lower limit in the integral should be a positive number.

Comment: @littleO and Behnam, couldn't agree more. There is the little problem of actually  showing differentiability, but intuitively I think this is a great approach, since already the students understand functions like $2^x, 10^x.$

Comment: Sure. It was meant to be $1$. Sorry my bad.

Answer (score 0):

My favorite way is to
look for solutions to
the functional equation
$f(x+y) = f(x)f(y)$.

Setting $y=0$,
we get
$f(0) = 1$.

If we assume that they are differentiable,
$f(x+h)= f(x)f(h)
$,
so

$\begin{array}\\
f(x+h)-f(x)
&= f(x)f(h)-f(x)\\
&= f(x)(f(h)-1)\\
\text{so}\\
\dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}
&= \dfrac{f(x)(f(h)-1)}{h}\\
&= f(x)\dfrac{f(h)-1}{h}\\
\end{array}
$

Letting $h \to 0$,
this gives
$f'(x) = f'(0)f(x)$,
so that
$f(x) = a^x$
where
$f'(0) = \ln(a)$.

$e$ is the value
that makes
$f'(0) = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

One important property of $e$ (some would say *the* important property) is that $\frac{d}{dx} e^x = e^x$. Since we know that $a^0 = 1$ for any nonzero $a$, this property can be used to find the Taylor expansion about 0, since for $f(x) = e^x$, $f^{(n)}(0)=1 \forall n$.

$$e^x = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n f^{(n)}(0)}{n!} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}$$

Since $1^n = 1 \forall n$,

$$e^1 = e = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!}$$

Another way to look at this is to examine what happens when you take the derivative of the Taylor series:

$$\frac{d}{dx} e^x = \frac{d}{dx}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!} = \frac{d}{dx}\left(1 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}\right) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{d}{dx}\frac{x^n}{n!}= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{nx^{n-1}}{n!} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!} = e^x$$

Similarly, when you integrate the Taylor series, you also get the same Taylor series back (plus a constant of integration).